# How do I make this function decide if True, than divide by variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing a program to determine the positivity rate in icu's. I give a list: in_hospitals and in_icu, and I need to divide **only** the True values in the list by the true values to get the positivity rate %

This is the list:

```
in_hospitals = [True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]
in_icu= [True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]
```

The function:

```
def rate_icu(hospitals, icu):
                        hospitalized =  len(icu) / len(hospital) 
                        rate = hospitalized
                        return rate 


rate = rate_icu(hospitals, icu)
print(rate) #Testing Code
```

The function returns 1 because it just divides 8 by 8, but I need it to divide only the True values in the list above

Desired Output:

```
33.333333333333336
```

Comment: return sum(in_icu)/sum(in_hospitals)

Comment: " I give a list: in_hospitals and in_icu, and I need to divide only the True values in the list" Which list is "the list"? Why are you considering both lists at once? " divide only the True values in the list by the true values" I don't understand what this means. Please think more clearly  about exactly what should be the numerator and denominator for the division. If you want, for example, to *count* some values that are in a list, then explicitly say so. But if you want to know the "positivity rate in ICUs", then I don't understand how anything to do with "hospitals" is relevant.

Comment: Holy indentation, Batman! That's 24 spaces for one level of indentation. Whatever editor is doing this to you, throw it in the trash with maximum prejudice.

Comment: Is there a reason you edited this question in a way that it's no longer useful to others? After your edits, this question no longer makes any sense. Assuming it's a mistake and rolling back.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`. With that, you can take the sum of the lists rather than the length:

```
in_hospitals = [True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]
in_icu= [True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]

def rate_icu(hospitals, icu):
                        hospitalized =  sum(icu) / sum(hospitals) 
                        rate = hospitalized
                        return rate 


rate = rate_icu(in_hospitals, in_icu)
print(rate) #Testing Code

# 0.3333333333333333
```

Of course if you want `33.33` you will need to multiply by 100.

Answer (score 2):

The "obvious" way is to `count` the quantity of `True` in each list:

```
icu.count(True) / hospital.count(True)
```

The "short-cut" way is to know that `Boolean` is a derived from `int`, with True = 1 and False = 0: simply use `sum`:

```
sum(icu) / sum(hospital)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *sum* instead of *len*:

```
    in_hospitals = [True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]
    in_icu= [True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]

    def rate_icu(hospitals, icu):
        hospitalized = (sum(icu) / sum(hospital)) * 100
        return hospitalized 


    rate = rate_icu(in_hospitals, in_icu)
    print(rate) #Testing Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the array

```
in_hospitals = [True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]
in_icu = [True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]


def rate_icu(hospital, icu):
    rate = len(icu) / len(hospital)
    return rate


rate = rate_icu([x for x in in_hospitals if x is True], [x for x in in_icu if x is True])
print(rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use sum

```py
in_hospitals = [True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True]
in_icu= [True, False, False, False, False, False, True, False]

def rate_icu(hospitals, icu):
                        hospitalized =  sum(icu) / sum(hospitals) 
                        rate = hospitalized * 100
                        return rate 


rate = rate_icu(in_hospitals, in_icu)
print(f"{rate} %")
```